# This blook need a value block connected to its socket KODULAR.IO

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbarU.jpg)

SOFTWARE. KODULAR.IO

When clicking the button, I would like it to show some text below. Cause this error! Have you tried using Chrome, Firefox and other browsers. But the error continues

When clicking the button, I would like it to show some text below. Cause this error! Have you tried using Chrome, Firefox and other browsers. But the error continues